# How to estimate survey data at cluster level in a stratified clustering survey design?

Tags: r, estimation, survey, stratification, cluster-sample

While estimating from the **survey data** involving **stratification** & **clustering** survey design and using survey package of **r**, is it possible to estimate at the **cluster level**? For eg; for following survey design:

```
data(api)
## syntax for stratified cluster sample
dclus=svydesign(id=~dnum, strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, nest=TRUE)
```

This is an example which is reproduced from the survey package. Here, *dnum* is district, *stype* is Elementary/Middle/High School and *pw* is weight (inverse of probalitlity of the students selected from each of the strata). In this case, can I estimate population parameter at district level? For example, to estimate total enrollment for each of the district:

```
svyby(~enroll,~dnum, design=dclus, svytotal)
```

I got the following output:

```
dnum   enroll       se
 19   21751.32   21751.32
 20   10494.50   10494.50
 25    9416.73    9416.73
 27   26923.30   26923.30
 40   14843.30   14843.30
 41   25774.43   25774.43
```

I believe this estimation is not correct, as no where I have given the break up of total students at district level (cluster level). 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800818/is-it-possible-to-estimate-at-survey-data-at-cluster-level/30822278#30822278

Comment: You game the number of students in each cluster when you wrote 'id=~dnum' in 'svydesign()'.